# $_POST not working when passed variable from Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Please excuse the basic question, I am new to all of this, but I'm keen to learn and have been trying to get this working for about 7 hours in total. No luck. I'm hoping you can help!

This is my Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
    $.post("http://www.mydomain.com/fbtest.php", { category: "<?php echo $vpostid; ?>" } );
    }
  );
</script>
```

And this is my fbtest.php code:

```
<?php
/** Set up WordPress environment */
require_once( './wp-load.php' );
require_once( './wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' );
require_once( './wp-includes/post.php' );

$vcatid = $_POST['category'];

$meta_val = get_post_meta($vcatid, 'fb_likes', true);

$fbmetval = intval($meta_val);
$fbmetval = $fbmetval + 1;

update_post_meta($vcatid, 'fb_likes', $fbmetval);

?>
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. I'm sure that I'm just missing something very basic.

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: What does the JavaScript look like after the PHP has generated it? What HTTP request is made? What HTTP response do you get? What (if any) JavaScript errors are reported on the JS console? Ditto PHP errors in your server's log files?

Comment: So what's the error? Are you sure that the code '<?php echo $vpostid; ?>' is actually sending an Id?

Comment: Why are you using `$vpostid` in the script but `$vcatid` in the PHP? `$vpostid` looks like it's supposed to contain a category.

Comment: @jwatts1980 `$vpostid` is for posting, the other one is on the landing page, nothing wrong there

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry but I don't actually know how to get that information...To test out what the values of the variables are I'm echoing them out to the page and looking at them.

Comment: To see the generated JS - view source. To see the HTTP request and response - look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. To see the JS console - use your browser's developer tools. To see the server logs … that depends on your server configuration. /var/log/apache/ is a common place.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I have checked that v$postid has a value because I can echo it out to the screen. It has a value of 845 for the post I'm looking to get working.

Comment: @Quentin I checked the source for my calling page and it says it's sending over {category: "845" } so that seems OK.
I've also tried hard-coding values for the get_post_meta but that doesn't seem to work. I thought maybe I wasn't including some kind of functions file or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Ajax in Plugins Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I found that I couldn't get AJAX to work in the normal way when working with Wordpress and had to setup handlers for it. The above link is certainly worth a look. I found it useful to follow the example first and then write what I wanted once I understood what was going on.

Comment: Hi @diggersworld, I did have a read of that and that's where I got the idea of adding the require_once( './wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ); at the top of the page.
I've now also tried adding global $wpdb but that doesn't help. Can you see anything obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: Including the `admin-ajax.php` file is not enough on it's own. You need to setup the action listeners so Wordpress knows what to do when a request comes in, e.g. `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');`. In the data from jQuery post you'll need to specify it as a POST variable: `action: 'my_action'`.